# What exactly does the command 'make reconfig' do when build Vim?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, compiling

I try to build VIM but I have a few question about `make` command and its options (now on Ubuntu 22.04).

For building VIM I follow the official documentation, first download the source files from its [repository](https://github.com/vim/vim).

The information is in the `INSTALL` [file](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/INSTALL). The steps are easy:

```
make
sudo make install
```

But I want to enable the clipboard function. The info isn't clear for me and I can't find information about the process.

If you want to have VIM with clipboard support is necessary follow the next steps:

```
# Install dependencies
sudo apt install libxt-dev
```

And (this the part that I can't understand):

```
make reconfig
```

How do I may to use this command? I can't understand the new steps, I think it must be this way (I already installed with `sudo make install`):

```
# Move to source files
sudo apt install libxt-dev
make reconfig
sudo make install
```

I think that is necessary uninstall first but I don't know, in the `man` file of `make` doesn't exist information about `reconfig`.